# Is it possible to import a CSV file into MySQL using VB.Net?

Tags: mysql, csv

I would like to know if it's possible to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` via VB.net to import a CSV given a path to the CSV.

Comment: Why can't you do this in code - i.e. line by line? Sometimes LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is disabled.

Comment: I have to a select path  for a file to upload...

Comment: This is a VB question - ask on Stack Overflow. Doesn't VB have a file select widget?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` is executed as a SQL statement and you can use vb.net to connect to MySQL and execute SQL statements. There are many good tutorials for this, but one way is to use the ODBC connection classes of the .net framework.

Keep in mind that because the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement is executed on the MySQL Server the path must be accessible to the server (not necessarily where the vb.net code is executing). If this isn't the case then you may want to read the file using vb.net insert each line into a table using `INSERT INTO` statements instead.